# Cross domain authentication of Web API

Tags: ajax, authentication, cross-domain, asp.net-web-api

I know this is an old question, and I have read many articles about it and finally reached here. Every thing works fine without authentication (without the [System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]):

1. The api controller:

   ```
   using System.Web.Http;
   using System.Web.Mvc;

   namespace WebApi.Controllers
   {
       [System.Web.Mvc.Authorize]
       public class ProductsController : ApiController
       {
           public IEnumerable<string> GetAllNames()
           {
               return new List<string> {"abc", "def", User.Identity.Name};
           }

           public string GetName(string name)
           {
               return name;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Web.Config
   The four lines under  are added to support CORS.

   ```
     <system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
       <modules>
         <remove name="WebDAVModule"/><!-- ADD THIS to enable POST/DELETE -->
       </modules>
       <handlers>
         <remove name="WebDAV" /><!-- ADD THIS to enable POST/DELETE -->
         <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
         <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
         <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
         <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
         <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
         <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
       </handlers>
       <httpProtocol>
         <customHeaders>
           <clear />
           <!-- Adding the following custom HttpHeaders will help prevent CORS from stopping the Request-->
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
           <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
         </customHeaders>
       </httpProtocol>
     </system.webServer>
   ```

But when the [Authorize] is added to the api controller, everything goes wrong.

Here is the the page call the api, there are up to 7 solutions that I read from the web, would be a textbook, if any of them worked. Many people said "it works for me", but none for me.

I commented all the solutions under the title, and recorded the error it caused.

```
        var host = 'http://localhost:54364/api/products/';
        userName = "name@domain.com";
        password = "password";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //Solution 1: OPTIONS http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone 405 (Method Not Allowed) / http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone. Invalid HTTP status code 405  
            //$.ajaxSetup({
            //    headers: {
            //        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa("cheny@cheny.com" + ":" + "nodenode")
            //    }
            //});
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: host + "GetAllNames",
                dataType: 'json',
                //Solution 2: Ok, but User.Identity.UserName returns "", an empty string; I think it does not work at all.
                //username: userName,
                //password: password,
                async: false,
                //Solution 3: GET http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone 405 (Method Not Allowed) / OPTIONS http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone 405 (Method Not Allowed) / XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone. Invalid HTTP status code 405
                //headers: { "Authorization": btoa("Basic " + userName + ":" + password) },
                //Solution 4: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames. Wildcards cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:64710' is therefore not allowed access.
                //xhrFields: {
                //    withCredentials: true
                //},
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    //Solution 5: Same with solution 2.
                    //xhr.withCredentials = true;
                    //Solution 6: OPTIONS http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone 405 (Method Not Allowed) / OPTIONS http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone 405 (Method Not Allowed)  / XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:54364/api/products/GetAllNames?name=someone. Invalid HTTP status code 405 
                    //xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(userName + ":" + password));
                    //Solution 7 ( 5 + 6 ): same with solution 6.
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                success:
                    function(data) {
                        // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                        $.each(data, function(key, item) {
                            // Add a list item for the product.
                            $('<li>', { text: formatItem(item) }).appendTo($('#ajax'));
                        });
                    }
            });
```

Being new with ajax and web api (just 2 days experience), I think I might missed something, for example, solution 4 has no username/password information, how could it work?

Thanks in advance, and any comments will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header of your response. If you are using authentication, then you can't use wildcard `*`. You need to explicitly set the domain.

And if you want to use `withCredentials: true` then your server must set an extra header `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` as `true`

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I'm not working on this testing now, I will give my feedback of what happens later :)